# TDBGrid TADTable displays duplicate rows when scrolling

Tags: c++builder, firedac

I have a `TDBGrid` with `TADTable` (FireDAC component to replace BDE TTable). The Table has an `ID (varchar(1)), Name (varchar(30)), Description(varchar2(400))`.
This is just to display, no calculations etc happening.
When associating the table to display the ID field of the table and I scroll up or down, duplicate records will appear in the grid:
so:

`A;B;C;D` will become `A;A;B;A;A;B;C;D;D`

This behavior stops if I remove the 400 char field from the table.

How do I make this work?

I am using C++Builder XE4, FireDac with Oracle 11g

I tried replacing TDBGrid with TDBAdvGrid from TMS (same issue), So TADTable?

Comment: is it just a redraw issue or is this real bad data?

Comment: It's a very simple table, 19 rows, not every Description field has data. When I hit the end of the table it keeps going duplicating the data in the grid not in the table.

Comment: What is `TADTable`? It's not part of the standard VCL, AFAICT (it's not in the documentation anywhere, and I can't find it on the component palette).

Comment: TADTable is a FireDAC (ANYDAC) vcl for XE4 that is a replacement for BDE. It is similiar to TTable.

Comment: You may be better off with a component we are familiar with, like TADOTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/firedac/Browsing_Table.html.
Pay attention to "Avoiding "unique key violation" error in LDV".

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand about client sort collation vs Server sort collation. But Setting the FetchOptions.CursorKind to ckDefault solved our issues.